# On Click event Javascript - Not loading Image

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    $(function(){
    var model = {
        init: function() {
            imageArray = [];
            imageArray[0] = {
            id: 0,
            image01 : new Image(),
            src : "c0.jpg",
            imageCaption : "cat0",
            count: 0
            };
            imageArray[1] = {
            id: 1,
            image01 : new Image(),
            src : "c1.jpg",
            imageCaption : "cat1",
            count: 0
            };
            imageArray[2] = {
            id: 2,
            image01 : new Image(),
            src : "c2.jpeg",
            imageCaption : "cat2",
            count: 0
            };
            imageArray[3] = {
            id: 3,
            image01 : new Image(),
            src : "c3.jpeg",
            imageCaption : "cat3",
            count: 0
            };
            imageArray[4] = {
            id: 4,
            image01 : new Image(),
            src : "c4.jpg",
            imageCaption : "cat4",
            count: 0
             };
        },
        returnImages: function() {
            return imageArray.map(function(e){
            return e;
            });
        }
    };


    var octopus = {
        openAll: function() {
            return model.returnImages();
        },
        init: function() {
            model.init();
            view1.init();
            view2.init();
        },
        open: function(id) {
            return imageArray[id];
        }


    };
    var view1 = {
        init: function() {
            this.catList = $('#elems');
            view1.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            var htmlStr = '';
            octopus.openAll().forEach(function(image){
                htmlStr += "<li><img id =\"clickme\" src='"+ image.src +"' alt='"+image.imageCaption+"' width=\"160\" height=\"120\"/></li></hr><br/>";
            });
            this.catList.html(htmlStr);
        }
    };
    var view2 = {
        init: function() {
            this.showCat = $('#show');
            this.clickme = $('#clickme');
            this.clickme.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            view2.render(e.id);
        });

        },
        render: function(id){
            var htmlStr = '';
            octopus.open().forEach(function(image){
                htmlStr += "<li><img id="addcount" src='"+image.src+"' width=\"500\" height=\"500\"/></li></hr><br/>";
            });
            this.showCat.html(htmlStr);
        }
    };


    octopus.init();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>cat Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul id="elems" class = "elems"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div id = "show"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Above is the quick structure of my code.

Im trying build an Image Gallery where a list of small image icons will be displayed and on click of each icon , the image will open in the same page in a bigger size. I'm able to display the list of images and my on click function goes wrong somewhere.

In my javascript code I have four var named model, octopus, view1 and view2. view1 displays the list of icons and view 2 is to display the image in a bigger size. model holds all the data and basic operations and octopus is the controller of views and models.

Please help me figure out whats wrong here.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you put  fiddle for this, its hard to debug in this mode

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nrsb0jvx/2/

Comment: cc.js is missing, double check before post

Comment: Are you sure? I'm able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You create some images with the id "clickme". That is the first mistake because multiple ids are not allowed. You should change that to a class and additionally add the picture.ID as ID-attribute to that image.

Then your next step is to attach the event-Handler for the images. and within that function you try to use event.id wich has nothing to do with the image id. In fact the render function for view2 does not use the id at all because you forget to give it octopus.open() as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
htmlStr += "<li><img id='addcount' src='"+image.src+"' width='500' height='500'/></li></hr><br/>";
```